# values of levelOfDetail and levelsOfDetailBias to render pdf on CATiledLayer in ios

Tags: ipad, pdf, memory-management, catiledlayer, pdf-rendering

i am developing a project in which i render PDF on the CATiledLayers.I have Used the CGPdf class methods to render the pdf and succeeded too.

I would like to know the values to be used for **levelsOfDetail** and **levelsOfDetailBias** for avoiding any memory issues either in normal mode or zoom mode.
Right now i am setting the values a s below.

tiledLayer1.levelsOfDetail = 1;
tiledLayer1.levelsOfDetailBias = 30;

Am i using the appropriate values and does the memory get affected with these values?

I got this doubt since i am facing memory issues on zooming the page.I ensured there are no memory leaks and the code is effectively written.

my zoomScale ranges between 1.0 to 2.0.
Can anyone help me out to avoid the memory issue...and the values to be used for the above parameters.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can try reducing the levelsOfDetailBias. But one thing you should keep in mind is that whatever you do, memory warnings would certainly appear,we just need to handle it.

For instance, a simple pdf page may not trigger memory warning at all in any zoom level, whereas pdf page with high quality images may lead to memory warning. Also memory warning depends on the entire device on what is available for the application to run.